# Angular Service injection can't find it's internal functions

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angularjs and have an issue using my service method in my controller.

this is my controller and my service structure:

```
var myfirstApp= angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngCookies']);
myfirstApp.service("UserService",['$location',"$http","$timeout",function($location,$http,$timeout){
    var User={};
    var CheckAuthenticationURL="/fa/home/IsAuthenticate";
    if($location.protocol() == "https")
    {
      CheckAuthenticationURL="https://www.mytest.org/fa/home/IsAuthenticateSecure";
    }
    var UpdateUserData= function(){
      $http.get(CheckAuthenticationURL)
        .then(function(UserInfo){
          $timeout(function() {
          User=UserInfo.data;
          console.log(User);
          }, 0);
        })
    };

    var getUser= function()
    {
      UpdateUserData().then(function(){
        return User;
      });
    }
    return{
      UpdateUserData: UpdateUserData,
      getUser: getUser
    };
  }]);

myfirstApp.controller('GeneralCtrl',['$scope','$http','UserService', function($scope,$http,UserService) {
    $scope.User={};
    $scope.User=UserService.getUser();
  }]);
```

but when page loads and General controller is called I get this error which says the UpdateUserData is undefined:

```
> Error: UpdateUserData(...) is undefined getUser@/mytest.org/:2691:7
> @/mytest.org/:2704:17
> d@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:34:209
> g/<.instantiate@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:34:340
> Xd/this.$get</<@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:66:70
> H/<@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:52:434
> q@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:7:384
> H@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:52:1
> f@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:46:314
> f@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:46:331
> x/<@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:45:490
> cc/c/</<@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:18:63
> ge/this.$get</h.prototype.$eval@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:108:478
> ge/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:109:230
> cc/c/<@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:18:21
> d@//mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:34:209
> cc/c@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:17:1
> cc@//mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:18:140
> ed@/mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:17:215
> @//mytest.org/js/fa/all_angular_and_services3.81.min.js:212:459
> p.Callbacks/k@//mytest.org/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:16915
> p.Callbacks/l.fireWith@/mytest.org/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:17707
> .ready@/mytest.org/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:12436
> D@/mytest.org/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:9841 
> e/<()
```

where would be the problem?

Comment: add 'return' keyword in your `UpdateUserData`. `return $http.get(CheckAuthenticationURL)`

Comment: The problem was resolved, tnx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UpdateUserData().then(...)
```

You're calling `UpdateUserData()`, and then call `then()` on the value returned by `UpdateUserData()`. But `UpdateUserData()` doesn't return anything.

Instead of

```
$http.get(CheckAuthenticationURL)
```

you probably want

```
return $http.get(CheckAuthenticationURL)
```